# remove first element from a list of sublist in an efficient way [python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

If I have a list like this:

```
my-list = [[[3, 1], [3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1]], [[4, 1], [4, 0]]]
```

and I want to remove the first element of each "pair" of sublists like

```
my-list = [ [1,0,0,1] , [1,0] ]
```

In the example above, the 3's and the 4's (first element) from the 2nd highest sublist are dropped. What is the most efficient way of achieving this?

Thank You!

Comment: Do you have a way of doing it currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension to work it out:

```
my_list = [[[3, 1], [3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1]], [[4, 1], [4, 0]]]
new_list = [[x[1] for x in w] for w in my_list] 
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0]]
```